# MutableLiveData doesn't return HashMap object after Retrofit finishes downloading my data and updating the HashMap

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-livedata

So, I recently learned Retrofit and was trying to create an application that uses an API to download Pokemon details. Here's the code for the MainActivity.java class and the MainActivityViewModel.java class. There are other classes there but they are mostly the Model classes and so I haven't mentioned them:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.arpansircar.java.pokemonapplication.R;
import com.arpansircar.java.pokemonapplication.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MainActivityViewModel mainActivityViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        observeRetrofitFailures();

        mainActivityViewModel.downloadMainPokemonData();
        mainActivityViewModel.returnMainDownloadedData().observe(this, resultsPokemonServiceModels ->
                mainActivityViewModel.downloadSelectedPokemonData(resultsPokemonServiceModels));

        mainActivityViewModel.returnDownloadedPokemonData().observe(this, map -> {

        });
    }

    private void observeRetrofitFailures() {
        mainActivityViewModel.returnMainServiceErrorLiveData().observe(this, s ->
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

        mainActivityViewModel.returnSelectedPokemonServiceErrorLiveData().observe(this, s ->
                Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }
}
```

**MainActivityViewModel.java**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import com.arpansircar.java.pokemonapplication.model.GetPokemonId;
import com.arpansircar.java.pokemonapplication.model.MainPokemonServiceModel;
import com.arpansircar.java.pokemonapplication.model.ResultsPokemonServiceModel;
import com.arpansircar.java.pokemonapplication.model.SelectedPokemonModel;
import com.arpansircar.java.pokemonapplication.retrofit.MainPokemonRetrofitInstance;
import com.arpansircar.java.pokemonapplication.retrofit.PokemonServiceInterface;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.internal.EverythingIsNonNull;

public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MainPokemonServiceModel mainPokemonServiceModel;
    private final Map<String, String> pokemonHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final PokemonServiceInterface mainPokemonServiceInterface = MainPokemonRetrofitInstance.getInstance();

    private final MutableLiveData<String> mainServiceErrorLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<String> selectedPokemonServiceErrorLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<Map<String, String>> downloadMainPokemonData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<List<ResultsPokemonServiceModel>> resultsPokemonServiceModelListLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void downloadMainPokemonData() {
        Call<MainPokemonServiceModel> mainPokemonServiceModelCall = mainPokemonServiceInterface.getResultsDataFromService();
        mainPokemonServiceModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<MainPokemonServiceModel>() {

            @Override
            @EverythingIsNonNull
            public void onResponse(Call<MainPokemonServiceModel> call, Response<MainPokemonServiceModel> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    mainServiceErrorLiveData.postValue(String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    return;
                }

                mainPokemonServiceModel = response.body();
                resultsPokemonServiceModelListLiveData.postValue(Objects.requireNonNull(mainPokemonServiceModel).resultsPokemonServiceModel);
            }

            @Override
            @EverythingIsNonNull
            public void onFailure(Call<MainPokemonServiceModel> call, Throwable t) {
                mainServiceErrorLiveData.postValue(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public void downloadSelectedPokemonData(List<ResultsPokemonServiceModel> resultsPokemonServiceModelList) {
        for (ResultsPokemonServiceModel resultsPokemonServiceModel : resultsPokemonServiceModelList) {
            String pokemonId = GetPokemonId.getId(resultsPokemonServiceModel.url);
            Call<SelectedPokemonModel> selectedPokemonModelCall = MainPokemonRetrofitInstance.getInstance().getSelectedPokemonSprite(pokemonId);

            selectedPokemonModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<SelectedPokemonModel>() {
                @Override
                @EverythingIsNonNull
                public void onResponse(Call<SelectedPokemonModel> call, Response<SelectedPokemonModel> response) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        selectedPokemonServiceErrorLiveData.postValue(String.valueOf(response.code()));
                        return;
                    }

                    SelectedPokemonModel selectedPokemonModel = response.body();
                    String pokemonName = Objects.requireNonNull(selectedPokemonModel).pokemonName;
                    String pokemonSpriteUrl = selectedPokemonModel.pokemonSpriteModel.spriteUrl;
                    pokemonHashMap.put(pokemonName, pokemonSpriteUrl);
                }

                @Override
                @EverythingIsNonNull
                public void onFailure(Call<SelectedPokemonModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    selectedPokemonServiceErrorLiveData.postValue(t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        downloadMainPokemonData.postValue(pokemonHashMap);
    }

    public LiveData<Map<String, String>> returnDownloadedPokemonData() {
        return downloadMainPokemonData;
    }

    public LiveData<List<ResultsPokemonServiceModel>> returnMainDownloadedData() {
        return resultsPokemonServiceModelListLiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<String> returnMainServiceErrorLiveData() {
        return mainServiceErrorLiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<String> returnSelectedPokemonServiceErrorLiveData() {
        return selectedPokemonServiceErrorLiveData;
    }

}
```

My main problem is at the line `downloadMainPokemonData.postValue(pokemonHashMap);`. When the download finishes, the MutableLiveData object (for some reason) isn't notified about this, i.e., the HashMap isn't returned back to the MainActivity.

I put some log checks and found the method is indeed being triggered. However, the system exits the method even before the download is completed. The download does get completed, yes. But for some reason, it doesn't return the downloaded HashMap back to the MainActivity. I think that this could be because the enqueue method provided by Retrofit is asynchronous and does all the tasks in a background thread.

Could someone provide any hints as to how I can take care of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectedPokemonModelCall.enqueue` is async request. `downloadMainPokemonData.postValue(pokemonHashMap)` called before `Response<SelectedPokemonModel>` data was handled

Comment: Where do you recommend I put the downloadMainPokemonData.postValue(...) code so the data to be handled at the right time?

Comment: @ArpanSircar you can use it inside `public void onResponse` but it's inside loop, so you'll get a lot of useless values. I would recommend to use synchronous call  `selectedPokemonModelCall.execute()` and when loop reaches the end you get data in one piece. And don't forget to use `Thread`. For more info check https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/retrofit-sync-async-calls/

Comment: This might be asking for a lot but is there any way that I can use the `enqueue` method and get the data in one piece at the end? I haven't really learned how to make asynchronous calls. And I tried out the `execute` method without multithreading but it returns the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: @ArpanSircar that's why i said - don't forget to use `Thread`. Wrap foreach with `Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      for(...){....}
    downloadMainPokemonData.postValue(pokemonHashMap)
    }
  }
  thread.start();`